# how to get a list of merged files in git?

Tags: git

For a given merge commit, how can I find out which files combined changes from two or more parents (with or without conflict)?

And, here is an example, just for good measure:

```
A -- B -- C -- E-- .. 
      \-- D --/
```

I have the following files

- B has f1, f2, f3, f5, f6
- C modifies f1 and f3. Removes f2
- D modifies f1, f3, and f6. Adds f4.
- E is the merge commit, has f1, f3, f4, f5 and f6.

I am looking for the git command that returns the list "f1 f3" in E, because in E, those are the only two files that were changed by **both C and D**. All others were either not touched, or updated by a single parent only.

The use case is the following: A company has an SCM (not git) in which developers commit changesets (list of files) to a temporary branch. The commit needs to pass through a scrutiny of tests and peer review, before it could be accepted to the main development branch.  Occasionally (and by that I mean frequently), development branch progresses after the commit, at which time some of the files needs to be merged (and remerged) before they could be accepted to the development branch.

In the above example, bottom line represents the temporary branch and D is my under-review changeset. The top line is the main dev branch and C is the commit that moved on in the meantime. In E, I have my changes approved and have updated and merged with the new dev-branch. Now the task is to come up with a list of files that I need to push upstream to the company SCM (remember, that is a manual changeset I need to come up with).  Among the files that were changed in E are those that I have modified or added in D and have already pushed upstream and have no counterparts or were not touched in the dev branch (in C). And also in E are the files that were modified in the dev branch by others and I had nothing to do with.  These are the files with a **single** parent. The remainder are the files that were merged (automatically by Git, or by myself in case of conflicts). And that is the list I need to push up.

Comment: I'm confused by the question. Can't you just look at the list of files modified by commit E?

Comment: You mean, files that have changes from both parents?  What do you want for an octopus merge, files that have changes from "more than one" or "all" or "more than 50% of" parents, or what?  Or just "files that are common to both (all/many) parents"?

Comment: Files that have been merged. I.e. files that were modified by two or more parents, with or without conflicts. For octopus, that'd be "more than one", yes. "Files that are common to both [(or more)] parents". I added a use case for the example.

Comment: and we have to agree to the definition of "common files": set of files that were *modified* by two or more parents, are the "common" set for those parents.  Otherwise, this is one source tree, of course ALL files are common (in the straightforward sense of the word meaning that they /exist/ in all branches :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(late edit: diff-tree's `-c` lists only the files that differ from all parents i.e. is exactly what was asked for:

```
git diff-tree -r -c $commit  # content that doesn't match any parent version
```

)
( later edit: the above is actually not quite true: what was requested and what  the script below prints is all files having multiple parents with changes since the merge base. All such files by definition require merge resolution. The diff ignores files whose merge resolution was to take one parent as the result. 
)

---

Okay, from the edit it appears you want to generate a list of files to check for possible mis-merges by the merge driver, the files combining actual changes from at least two parents.  This'll do ya:

(edit: correctly handle merges that include no changes from a changed parent; also incorporate @torek's simplification.)

```
substantive-merges-in ()
{
    set -- `git rev-list $1^! --parents`;
    child=$1;
    shift;
    base=$(git merge-base "$@")
    for parent; do
        git diff-tree $base $parent -r --name-only --diff-filter=M
    done \
    | sort \
    | uniq -d
}
substantive-merges-in master
```

---

Testing:

```
git init t;cd t
git checkout -b first
# msysgit doesn't install `seq`?
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10; do echo $i >>both; done
cp both justfirst
git add *; git commit -minitial
git branch second
sed -i s/3/3onfirst/ both
sed -i s/3/3onfirst/ justfirst
git commit -amtwochanges
git checkout second
sed -i s/7/7onsecond/ both
git commit -amonechange
git merge first
substantive-merges-in HEAD          # should list 'both'
git checkout -B second second@{1}
git merge --no-commit first
git checkout --ours both
git commit -amstomp
substantive-merges-in HEAD          # should still list 'both'
```

Comment: Nice.  I'd still use `--diff-filter=M` here as you can then add `--name-only` and drop the `awk` entirely: `for parent do git diff-tree -r --diff-filter=M --name-only $parent $child; done | sort | uniq -d`.

Comment: mmm. I see that's true.  I've got list|filter|munge so wired I tend not to even consider filtering offered by the lister.  I'm editing the thing now to add a more-paranoid option, I'll incorporate your suggestion with thanks.

Comment: @jhill I rolled back your changes to the title. The question hasn't much to do with mis-merges at all: There is no "mis". All that is sought is the list of files that were changed concurrently (and hence were merged; manually when in conflict, automatically (by recursive strategy or whateever) when not). That's all. And I think your `substantive-merges-in()` does that already. I'll test and get back.

Answer (score 0):

I think this'll do it, maybe someone knows something more elegant

```
doit ()
{
    set -- `git rev-list $1^! --parents`;
    child=$1;
    shift;
    for parent; do
        git diff-tree $parent $child -r --raw \
        | awk '$1~/:100/ && $5=="M" {sub(/[^\t]*\t/,""); print}';
    done \
    | sort -u
}
doit master
```

Comment: I went with a different interpretation of the question, but we use similar techniques :-)  You could use `--diff-filter=M` to help out here, perhaps.

Comment: Yeah, this way will also list any gratuitous manual edits in the merge, which he didn't ask for, but the gut check keeps coming back they belong on the list, requested or not.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you mean is:

- commit `M` is a merge commit with two (or more) parents (`M^` and `M^2` at least)
- the complete tree for `M` is `T`
- you want to exclude from `T` any files that were not present in some parent(s)

then one straightforward method to do this is to start with the complete list `T`, and remove those files.  Here's a script that does that, without too much magic in it I think.  Lightly tested...

```
#! /bin/sh

PROG=$(basename $0)

case $# in
1) user_arg="$1";;
*) echo "usage: $PROG <commit>" >&2; exit 1;;
esac

# find full SHA1 of user-specified rev, plus all its parents
args=$(git rev-list --no-walk --parents "$user_arg") || exit 1
set -- $args

# omit this if you want to just list all files in a non-merge commit
case $# in
1|2) echo "$PROG: $user_arg is not a merge commit" >&2; exit 1;;
esac

# make temp file
TF=$(mktemp -t "$PROG") || exit 1
trap "rm -f $TF" 0 1 2 3 15

# save the SHA-1 of the commit, then toss that from arguments
c=$1
shift

# Now look at each parent: if the file was added between that
# parent and commit $c, it was not in that parent, so it's not
# "in common" across all parents to the final commit.  Dump
# such names into a "remove list".
#
# Remove duplicates from "remove" list.  Turn result into series
# of regexp's for "grep -v".  We need to:
#   1) protect any regexp metacharacters: turn . * ^ $ [ \ into
#      backslash-prefixed versions of same
#   2) add ^ at front and $ at end.
for parent do
    git diff-tree -r --name-only --diff-filter=A $parent $c
done | sort -u | sed -e 's/[.*^$[\]/\\&/g' -e 's/.*/^&$/' > $TF

# Now just run grep -v with that list, with input being the
# output of the "master list" of files in commit $c.
git ls-tree -r --name-only $c | grep -v -f $TF
```

If you mean something else, the `--diff-filter` above is tunable.

Answer (score 0):

OK, let's tackle a different "reasonably precise" definition based on the question-edit.

Given:

- merge commit `M`
- with final tree `T` containing files `f1`, `f2`, ..., `fn`
- and immediate parents `p1`, `p2`, ..., `pn`

you want—regardless of additional possible ancestry<sup>1</sup>—all files `fi` where, given any two different parents `pa` and `pb`, `fi` was "modified" in both `pa` and `pb`.

The definition of "modified" here is that for a commit `p` and file `f`, `p` itself has one single parent, `p^` (so `p` is neither a merge nor a root commit), and `p:f` (file `f` in commit `p`) differs from `p^:f` (possibly to the point of not even existing in `p^`).

This suggests the following obvious (and totally un-optimized) algorithm for finding all files `fi` in tree `T` that meet this constraint:

```
# set M = merge commit ID and P to its complete list of parents
# (see previous scripts for how to achieve that)
for f in $(git ls-tree -r $M); do
    found=false twice=false
    for p in $P; do
        $twice && continue # already announced
        if modified_in $p $f; then
           $found && twice=true || found=true
        fi
        $twice && echo $f  # announce if found twice
    done
done
```

where `modified_in` is defined as:

```
modified_in() {
    local p=$1 p_hat=$1^ path="$2"

    assert_single_parent $p # optional: verify neither root commit nor merge
    # (if you want to do this, it would be more efficient to do it once
    # outside the "for f in ..." loop)
    test ! -z "$(git diff-tree -r --diff-filter=AM $p_hat $p -- "$path")"
}
```

Here the `git diff-tree` command will output a line like:

```
:100644 100644 <sha1_in_p^> <sha1_in_p> M   c
```

for a file modified between `$p_hat` and `$p` (the *`sha1`* values being the blob SHA-1s), and:

```
:000000 100644 <null_sha1> <sha1_in_p> A    fgh
```

for a file added there.  The `--diff-filter=AM` ensures no output for a removal (otherwise you would get an `R` here) and the `-- "$path"` limits the checking to just the given file-name-path.  I am pretty sure (but have not tested) that you need not worry about `C` and `R` (copy-edit and rename) and since these are commit tree diffs, not index diffs, `U` (unmerged) cannot occur.  So we just need to run `git diff-tree` with that filter, and test whether the command prints anything.

(To make this [probably much] more efficient, run all possible `git diff-tree` commands once, without specifying paths, on all "interesting" parents, saving their outputs, then cross-correlate all the files listed.  Those that occur twice or more are your candidates.  But that's much harder in `sh` script: you'll need something like `awk` here.)

[Edit: no, you don't need `awk` after all, `sort | uniq -d` will do the trick.  See [jthill's new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19139966/1256452), which implements the much-more-efficient version of a slightly different interpretation of the question, maybe closer to the real intent, which I admit I still find confusing.]

---

<sup>1</sup>That is, if the commit graph looks something like this, for instance:

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- M -- .. 
      \-- E -- F --/
```

you only care about changes made in `D` and `F` with respect to `M`, not changes made in `C` and `E` as well.

If you *do* care, you may want to diff commit `M` against, e.g., temporary trees made by squashing together C-and-D, and E-and-F, respectively; or do pairwise comparisons all the way back, or some such.  Basically, you will need to list revs between the merge-base (commit `B`, here) and the merge itself (`M`), and then figure out how you want to handle them.